# if statement, function evaluation & compiler optimization

Tags: c, if-statement, compiler-optimization, volatile, evaluation

Just a quick question, to save me from testing things (although I really *should* test things to be absolutely certain):

Given the following C code:

```
r1 = fun1();
r2 = fun2();

if (r1 && r2)
{
   // do something
}
```

Variables `r1` and `r2` are not being used anywhere else in the code, except in the `if (...)` statement. Will both functions be evaluated? I'm worried that the compiler may optimize the code by eliminating `r1` and `r2`, thus making it look like this:

```
if (fun1() && fun2())
{
   // do something
}
```

In this case, `fun1()` will be evaluated first, and if it returns `FALSE`, then `fun2()` will *not* be evaluated at all. This is *not* what I want, and that's the reason why I'm coding it as in the first code segment.

How can I guarantee that a function will *always* be evaluated? I thought that this could be done by assigning it to a variable, but I'm concerned about compiler optimization if it sees that this variable is never actually being used later on in the code...

I know this can be achieved by declaring `r1` and `r2` as `volatile`, but I'd like to know if there's a more elegant solution.

Any comments on this issue are greatly appreciated, thanks!

---

**Edit:** Thanks to all who replied. I've just used my first code snippet on my project (it's an ARM Cortex-M7-based embedded system). It appears that the compiler does *not* optimize the code in the way I showed above, and *both* `fun1()` and `fun2()` are evaluated (as they should). Furthermore, compiling the code with `r1` and `r2` declared as `volatile` produces exactly the same binary output as when `r1` and `r2` are just normal variables (i.e., the `volatile` keyword doesn't change the compiler output at all). This reassures me that the first code snippet is in fact a guaranteed way of evaluating *both* functions prior to processing the `if (...)` statement that follows.

Comment: You'd probably have to look at the disassembly.

Comment: it will not optimize the calls out unless it can evaluate the result compile time

Comment: @FiddlingBits That won’t tell you anything reliable, since the exact assembly can change at the drop of a hat, even with the same compiler. The only way to get reliable information is to defer to the specification here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the code does not exhibit any undefined behavior, compilers can only perform optimizations that have the same externally viewable behavior as the unoptimized code.

In your example, the two pieces of code do two different things.  Specifically, one always calls `fun2` while the other calls it conditionally.  So you don't need to worry about the first piece of code doing the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1):

The calls will not be optimized out unless the result of the calls can be computed compile time.

```
void foo()
{
    int r1 = fun1();
    int r2 = fun2();

    if (r1 && r2)
    {
        func3();
    }
}

int fun3() {return 1;}
int fun4() {func();return 0;}

void bar()
{
    int r1 = fun3();
    int r2 = fun4();

    if (r1 && r2)
    {
        func3();
    }
}

foo:
        push    {r4, lr}
        bl      fun1
        mov     r4, r0
        bl      fun2
        cmp     r4, #0
        cmpne   r0, #0
        popeq   {r4, pc}
        pop     {r4, lr}
        b       func3
fun3:
        mov     r0, #1
        bx      lr
fun4:
        push    {r4, lr}
        bl      func
        mov     r0, #0
        pop     {r4, pc}
bar:
        b       func
```